Where should I include the details of the trip?
In which document should I include the details (timetable) of my stay in the UK when applying for a visa? Should I mention it in my letter or write it in a separate document specialized for “the timetable of my travel stay”?

IIRC there is a section in the online application itself that asks about your proposed itinerary. You can also provide the information in your covering letter and/or the ‘additional information’ section at the end of the application. In my experience it is not necessary to provide a day-by-day, massively detailed breakdown of how you plan to spend your time. Just mention the most important / longest of your plans eg sightseeing destinations.
Note that having a great itinerary won’t count for much if other aspects of your application (eligibility, travel history, ties to home etc) don’t stack up. Also note that the UK explicitly states you should not book flights before getting the  visa application decision. Proof of travel is not required to be submitted with your application.
